# QGIS: georeferencing report: tail cutted off

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, pdf

I'm using QGIS 1.8.0-2 to georeference some old maps and want to report residuals and other information via the PDF report function of the [Georeferencer tool](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/html/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html). If there's too much information, it's cut off at the bottom of the PDF page.

Is there a way to get all the information (i.e. on a second page)?

Regards,

Thomas

Comment: I've asked the very same question to the QGIS user list. It seems that there is no way of doing it, except if you have programing skills to alter the source code (which I don't have). Please let us know if you found a way around. Regards, Alessandro